# network values goes to 0 by linear layers

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, attention-model

I designed the Graph Attention Network.
However, during the operations inside the layer, the values of features becoming equal.

```
class GraphAttentionLayer(nn.Module):
    ## in_features = out_features = 1024
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, dropout):
        super(GraphAttentionLayer, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
   
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(in_features, out_features)))
        self.a1 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(out_features, 1)))
        self.a2 = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(out_features, 1)))
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.W.data, gain=1.414)
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.a1.data, gain=1.414)
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.a2.data, gain=1.414)
        self.leakyrelu = nn.LeakyReLU()

    def forward(self, input, adj):
        h = torch.mm(input, self.W)
        a_input1 = torch.mm(h, self.a1)
        a_input2 = torch.mm(h, self.a2)
        a_input = torch.mm(a_input1, a_input2.transpose(1, 0))
        e = self.leakyrelu(a_input)

        zero_vec = torch.zeros_like(e)
        attention = torch.where(adj > 0, e, zero_vec) # most of values is close to 0
        attention = F.softmax(attention, dim=1) # all values are 0.0014 which is 1/707 (707^2 is the dimension of attention)
        attention = F.dropout(attention, self.dropout)
        return attention
```

The dimension of 'attention' is (707 x 707) and I observed the value of attention is near 0 before the softmax.
After the softmax, all values are 0.0014 which is 1/707.
I wonder how to keep the values normalized and prevent this situation.

Thanks

Comment: When does this happen, do you have a final trained model you want to execute or is this during training?

Comment: @Nopileos It happens during the training. I doubt the softmax function is not effective when the dimension of feature is much big. i.e., we use softmax for classification with the dimension of 2 and the output forms like [0.001, 0.999]. But for the feature has the dimension over 1k, the value will be equal due to the exponential in the function, 
especially for the small values ((e^0.0001) ~ 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say this happens during training I would assume it is at the start. With random initialization you often get near identical values at the end of the network during the start of the training process.

When all values are more or less equal the output of the softmax will be `1/num_elements` for every element, so they sum up to 1 over the dimension you chose. So in your case you get `1/707` as all the values, which just sounds to me your weights are freshly initialized and the outputs are mostly random at this stage.

I would let it train for a while and observe if this changes.

Comment: Hey if it answered your questions please accept it or tell what is missing. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, sry :) I just forgot